# Restrict text widget to only integer between 0 and 999 in IntraMaps Roam

Tags: python, intramaps-roam

I have created a form and added an attribute as a Text widget in the Roam manager.

Now I'm trying to restrict the input to be an integer between 0 and 999. I want the field to stay "empty" (or "blanc") as long as the user enter a letter and only to accept integers (but not more that 3 digits). If a 4th digit is entered, the field should continue only showing the 3 first allowed digits.

In QGIS I was able to achieve this with QIntValidator (but QIntValidator is not "available" i Roam?):

```
global gangeField
gangeField = myDialog.findChild(QLineEdit,"GANGE")
# gangeField will only accept inntegers between 0 and 999
validator = QIntValidator(0, 999, myDialog.findChild(QWidget,"tab2enhet"))
gangeField.setValidator(validator)
gangeField.textChanged.connect(felt_onTextChanged)
```

I have tried to add some Python (ver. 3.3.2) code in the __init__.py file, but only with limited success:

```
    def accept(self):
    """
    Called before the form is accepted.  Override this and return False to cancel the accepting of the form.
    :return:
    """
    # if ( int(self.boundwidgets['gange'].value()) == False ):
        # self.pushError("Angi integer!")
    if ( int(self.boundwidgets['gange'].value()) > 999 ):
        self.cancelload("Angi tall mellom 0 og 999")
    return True
```

Alternative: Can I change the error message to view my personalized text (e.g."Gange must be a number between 0 and 999.") for 2 seconds (like the Warning that is visible for 2 seconds if a required field is missing)?

Comment: I've found a way to view a warning by including `from roam.api import RoamEvents` in \__init__.py and then using raisemessage like `RoamEvents.raisemessage('Warning!','Use integer',1,2,'Gange must be in minutes between 0 and 999.')`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use

`from PyQt4.QtGui import QRegExpValidator` and `from PyQt4.QtCore import QRegExp`

then use the code:

`rx = QRegExp('^[1-9]\d{3}$')
validator = QRegExpValidator(rx)
self.boundwidgets['flatenr'].widget.setValidator(validator)`

See https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam/issues/239 for more details about the solution.